# SQL Cursor elimination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I need to migrate data in my application after introducing new table to db. I have prepared SQL script for that, but it uses cursor, which I want to elminiate due to performance issues (up to 2m of records in Configuration table).

What exactly I need to do is:

foreach config in Configuration where *related_id* is not null I need to migrate **TypeA** entity with id = *related_id* to **TypeB**; 
migrate all entities of type **ElementA**, which have reference to **TypeA** in column *TypeA_id*, to **ElementB**; also I need to update *related_id* on **Configuration** to newly created **TypeB** and delete migrated **ElementA** and **TypeA** entities.

```
DECLARE @RELATED INT,
    @CURRENT_CONFIG INT,
    @CREATED INT

DECLARE Crs SCROLL CURSOR FOR 
SELECT related_id, Id
FROM Configuration
WHERE related_id IS NOT NULL

OPEN Crs
FETCH NEXT FROM Crs INTO @RELATED, @CURRENT_CONFIG
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TypeB(col)
    SELECT col
    FROM TypeA
    WHERE Id = @RELATED

    SET @CREATED = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE Configuration
    SET related_id = @CREATED
    WHERE Id = @CURRENT_CONFIG

    INSERT INTO ElementB (TypeB_id, Col1)
    SELECT @CREATED, Col1
    FROM ElementA
    WHERE TypeA_id = @RELATED

    DELETE ElementA
    WHERE TypeA_id = @RELATED

    DELETE TypeA
    WHERE Id = @RELATED

    FETCH NEXT FROM Crs INTO @RELATED, @CURRENT_CONFIG
END
DEALLOCATE Crs
```

Do you think it is possible to eliminate cursor in my case?

Comment: what is the meaning of 2M, millions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use output clause here to get the inserted identity_col(idcol)

I assume the datatype of col as varchar(50).

```
        Create table #MyTable (idcol as int, col varchar(50));

            INSERT INTO TypeB
                        (col)
            OUTPUT INSERTED.identity_col --You need to relace identity_col with the actual identitycol.
                  ,INSERTED.col
                    INTO #MyTable
            SELECT col
            FROM   TypeA
            WHERE  Id IN(SELECT related_id
                         FROM   Configuration
                         WHERE  related_id IS NOT NULL)

--Add another column related_id in the temp table to get the original id

    ALTER TABLE #MyTable ADD related_id INT

    Update T
    set T.related_id=T1.id
    from #MyTable T
    JOIN TypeA T1
    on T.col= T1.col

            UPDATE A
            SET    a.related_id = B.idcol
            FROM   Configuration A
                    JOIN #MyTable B                
    ON B.related_id= A.related_id

        INSERT INTO ElementB (TypeB_id, Col1)
        SELECT distinct B.idcol, A.Col1
        FROM ElementA A 
        JOIN #MyTable B on A.TypeA_id= B.related_id

    DELETE ElementA
    WHERE  TypeA_id IN (SELECT distinct related_id
                        FROM   #MyTable)

    DELETE TypeA
    WHERE  Id IN (SELECT distinct related_id
                        FROM   #MyTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Cursor` can be eliminated. Try this.

```
INSERT INTO TypeB
            (col)
SELECT col
FROM   TypeA
WHERE  Id IN(SELECT related_id
             FROM   Configuration
             WHERE  related_id IS NOT NULL)

UPDATE A
SET    related_id = b.identity_col  -- replace identity_col with TypeB identity column name
FROM   Configuration A
       JOIN TypeB B
         ON a.Id = b.related_id

INSERT INTO ElementB
            (TypeB_id,Col1)
SELECT @CREATED,Col1
FROM   ElementA A
       JOIN TypeB B
         ON a.Id = a.TypeB_id
       JOIN (SELECT related_id
             FROM   Configuration
             WHERE  related_id IS NOT NULL) C
         ON A.TypeA_id = c.related_id 

DELETE ElementA
WHERE  TypeA_id IN (SELECT related_id
                    FROM   Configuration
                    WHERE  related_id IS NOT NULL)

DELETE TypeA
WHERE  Id IN (SELECT related_id
              FROM   Configuration
              WHERE  related_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: CREATED in my script is Id of newly created entity. In your script is set nowhere. As I understand how SCOPE_IDENTITY() it is not applicable here. Am I right? If yes, how to set proper value to CREATED variable?

Comment: @MattMcdon - check the update statement `SET related_id = b.identity_col` (ie) identity column of `TypeB` table

Comment: About update of A (line 9.) - unfortunately I don't have reference from **TypeA** and **TypeB** to Configuration. There is only *related_id* on configuration, which have id of **TypeA** and needs to have reference to **TypeB** after migration. On **ElementA** and **ElementB**, there is *TypeA_id* and *TypeB_id*